# HTML Purifier: Converting <body> to <div>

Tags: php, html-parsing, htmlpurifier, html

### Premise

I'd like to use [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org) to transform `<body>` tags to `<div>` tags, to preserve inline styling on the `<body>` element, e.g. `<body style="background:color#000000;">Hi there.</body>` would turn to `<div style="background:color#000000;">Hi there.</div>`. I'm looking at a combination of a [custom tag](http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-customize.html) and a `TagTransform` class.

### Current setup

In my configuration section, I'm currently doing this:

```
$htmlDef  = $this->configuration->getHTMLDefinition(true);
// defining the element to avoid triggering 'Element 'body' is not supported'
$bodyElem = $htmlDef->addElement('body', 'Block', 'Flow', 'Core');
$bodyElem->excludes = array('body' => true);
// add the transformation rule
$htmlDef->info_tag_transform['body'] = new HTMLPurifier_TagTransform_Simple('div');
```

...as well as allowing `<body>` and its `style` (and `class`, and `id`) attribute via the configuration directives (they're part of a working, large list that's parsed into `HTML.AllowedElements` and `HTML.AllowedAttributes`).

I've turned definition caching off.

```
$config->set('Cache.DefinitionImpl', null);
```

Unfortunately, in this setup, it seems like `HTMLPurifier_TagTransform_Simple` never has its `transform()` method called.

### HTML.Parent?

I presume the culprit is my `HTML.Parent`, which is set to `'div'` since, quite naturally, `<div>` does not allow a child `<body>` element. However, setting `HTML.Parent` to `'html'` nets me:

> ErrorException: Cannot use unrecognized element as parent

Adding...

```
$htmlElem = $htmlDef->addElement('html', 'Block', 'Flow', 'Core');
$htmlElem->excludes = array('html' => true);
```

...gets rid of that error message but still doesn't transform the tag - it's removed instead.

Adding...

```
$htmlElem = $htmlDef->addElement('html', 'Block', 'Custom: head?, body', 'Core');
$htmlElem->excludes = array('html' => true);
```

...also does nothing, because it nets me an error message:

```
ErrorException: Trying to get property of non-object       

[...]/library/HTMLPurifier/Strategy/FixNesting.php:237
[...]/library/HTMLPurifier/Strategy/Composite.php:18
[...]/library/HTMLPurifier.php:181
[...]
```

I'm still tweaking around with the last option now, trying to figure out the exact syntax I need to provide, but if someone knows how to help me based on their own past experience, I'd appreciate any pointers in the right direction.

### HTML.TidyLevel?

As the only other culprit I can imagine it being, my `HTML.TidyLevel` is set to `'heavy'`. I've yet to try all possible constellations on this, but so far, this is making no difference.

(Since I've only been touching this secondarily, I struggle to recall which constellations I've already tried, lest I would list them here, but as it is I lack confidence I wouldn't miss something I've done or misreport something. I might edit this section later when I've done some dedicated testing, though!)

### Full Configuration

My configuration data is stored in JSON and then parsed into HTML Purifier. Here's the file:

```
{
    "CSS" : {
        "MaxImgLength" : "800px"
    },
    "Core" : {
        "CollectErrors" : true,
        "HiddenElements" : {
            "script"   : true,
            "style"    : true,
            "iframe"   : true,
            "noframes" : true
        },
        "RemoveInvalidImg" : false
    },
    "Filter" : {
        "ExtractStyleBlocks" : true
    },
    "HTML" : {
        "MaxImgLength" : 800,
        "TidyLevel"    : "heavy",
        "Doctype"      : "XHTML 1.0 Transitional",
        "Parent"       : "html"
    },
    "Output" : {
        "TidyFormat"   : true
    },
    "Test" : {
        "ForceNoIconv" : true
    },
    "URI" : {
        "AllowedSchemes" : {
            "http"     : true,
            "https"    : true,
            "mailto"   : true,
            "ftp"      : true
        },
        "DisableExternalResources" : true
    }
}
```

(`URI.Base`, `URI.Munge` and `Cache.SerializerPath` are also set, but I've removed them in this paste. Also, `HTML.Parent` caveat: As mentioned, usually, this is set to `'div'`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is the reason why what you're doing doesn't work:

```
/**
 * Takes a string of HTML (fragment or document) and returns the content
 * @todo Consider making protected
 */
public function extractBody($html) {
    $matches = array();
    $result = preg_match('!<body[^>]*>(.*)</body>!is', $html, $matches);
    if ($result) {
        return $matches[1];
    } else {
        return $html;
    }
}
```

You can turn it off using %Core.ConvertDocumentToFragment as false; if the rest of your code is bugfree, it should work straight from there. I don't believe your bodyElem definition is necessary.j

Comment: *Ambush Commander to the rescue!* Thank you - awesome, this works! :D For completion's sake (if someone else stumbles across this): The `$bodyElem` definition seems to be necessary, still. I was also a bit concerned because `<title>blah</title>` was turning up `blah` in the final fragment, but then remembered the I can just add `'head'` to the `Core.HiddenElements` list. Now it works like a charm!

Comment: And another quick add-on for completion's sake: `<body>` and its `style`-attribute does not need to be in the tag whitelist, just the tag its transformed into (and its attribute).

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't it be much easier to do:

```
$search = array('<body', 'body>');
$replace = array('<div', 'div>');

$html = '<body style="background:color#000000;">Hi there.</body>';

echo str_replace($search, $replace, $html);

>> '<div style="background:color#000000;">Hi there.</div>';
```

Comment: On the final output of HTML Purifier, when I know nothing malicious has survived the process, that's probably indeed an option. However, before I end up overlooking something with a simple string-replace, I'd rather know I can rely on the solution; HTML Purifier parses and tokenises HTML reliably and given that I'm fairly sure whatever I'm overlooking is a small issue, I'd *definitely* rather have that solution. But, still, thank you. :)